Media Queries is not applying in MJML email framework
I'm very new to the MJML framework and im loving it so far, but im having an issue where whenever I turn my screen to mobile. The "Our latest blog" section is clipping into the "What our clients are saying" section above it. Additionally my Pulse logo wont align to the center when I change my screen to mobile.
<mjml>
  <mj-head>
    <mj-style inline="inline">
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=MonteCarlo&family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300..800;1,300..800&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
      * { 
        box-sizing: border-box; 
        font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif; 
      }
      .color-text { 
        color: purple; 
      } 
      .inline-text { 
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 12px; 
      }

      .jumbo {
        background-image: url("http://127.0.0.1:5502/assets/employee2.png" );
        background-size: 600px;
        height: 400px;
      }

      .script-text {
        font-family: "MonteCarlo", cursive;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
      }

      .customer-review {
        background-image: url("http://127.0.0.1:5502/assets/employee2.png" );
        background-size: 600px;
        height: 400px;
      } 

      @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .mj-section-padding-fix div {
          padding-top: 300px !important; /* Adjust as needed */
        }
        .logo-text {
          text-align: center !important;
        }
      }
    </mj-style>
  </mj-head>
  <mj-body background-color="lightgrey">
    <mj-wrapper background-color="#fff" padding="0">
      <mj-section background-color="black" padding="5px">
        <mj-column>
          <mj-text color="white" padding="13px 55px">
            1800-00-1234 | info@domain.com
          </mj-text>
        </mj-column>
      </mj-section>
      <mj-section background-color="#fff">
        <mj-column>
          <mj-text
            font-size="40px"
            font-weight="500"
            padding="0 40px"
            align="left"
            css-class="logo-text"
          >
            Pulse
          </mj-text>
        </mj-column>
        <mj-column padding="0">
          <mj-text
            font-size="16px"
            padding="18px 0 0"
            font-weight="600"
            align="center"
            color="#2B2B2B"
          >
            <span class="inline-text">Home</span>
            <span class="inline-text">About</span>
            <span class="inline-text">Blog</span>
            <span class="inline-text">Contact</span>
          </mj-text>
        </mj-column>
      </mj-section>
      <mj-section padding="0" css-class="jumbo">
        <mj-column>
        <mj-text font-size="50px" color="#ffffff" padding-top="80px" font-weight="700">
            Boost Your Business by Our Company
        </mj-text>
        <mj-text line-height="20px" font-size="15px" color="#ffffff" padding-right="100px">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus
            lacinia odio
          </mj-text>
          <mj-button align="left" border-radius="30px" font-size="15px">
            Learn More
          </mj-button>
          <!-- <mj-image
            alt="employee"
            src="http://127.0.0.1:5502/assets/employee.png"
            padding="0"
          /> -->
        </mj-column>
      </mj-section>
      <mj-section padding="40px 30px 20px 50px">
        <mj-column>
          <mj-text font-size="14px" font-weight="600" align="center">Article Title</mj-text>
          <mj-divider border-width="2px" border-style="solid" border-color="lightgrey" padding="0 20px"/>
          <mj-image src="http://127.0.0.1:5502/assets/businessmeet.jpg" padding="10px"/>
          <mj-text line-height="20px" font-size="12px" color="#929292">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus
            lacinia odio
          </mj-text>
        </mj-column>
        <mj-column>
          <mj-text font-size="14px" font-weight="600" align="center">Article Title</mj-text>
          <mj-divider border-width="2px" border-style="solid" border-color="lightgrey" padding="0 20px"/>
          <mj-image src="http://127.0.0.1:5502/assets/businessmeet.jpg" padding="10px"/>
          <mj-text line-height="20px" font-size="12px" color="#929292">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus
            lacinia odio
          </mj-text>
        </mj-column>
        <mj-column>
          <mj-text font-size="14px" font-weight="600" align="center">Article Title</mj-text>
          <mj-divider border-width="2px" border-style="solid" border-color="lightgrey" padding="0 20px"/>
          <mj-image src="http://127.0.0.1:5502/assets/businessmeet.jpg" padding="10px"/>
          <mj-text
            line-height="20px"
            font-size="12px"
            color="#929292"
            align="left"
          >
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus
            lacinia odio
          </mj-text>
        </mj-column>
      </mj-section>
      <mj-section padding="40px 25px 20px 25px">
        <mj-column>
          <mj-text
            font-size="35px"
            align="center"
            font-weight="bold"
            color="#2B2B2B"
          >
            Our Products are World Renown
          </mj-text>
          <mj-text align="center" color="#929292" font-size="14px">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          </mj-text>
        </mj-column>
      </mj-section>
      <mj-section padding="10px 20px 30px 20px">
        <mj-column>
          <mj-image src="http://127.0.0.1:5502/assets/pexels, businesswomen.jpg" />
        </mj-column>
        <mj-column>
          <mj-text
            align="left"
            color="#2B2B2B"
            font-size="25px"
            font-weight="600"
            padding-top="60px"
            line-height="35px"
          >
            We Provide Quality Services
          </mj-text>
          <mj-text align="left" color="#929292" font-size="16px" line-height="25px">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt 
          </mj-text>
          <mj-text font-size="20px" font-weight="600">
            Michael Clark
          </mj-text>
          <mj-text font-size="14px" color="#929292">
           Founder - Digital Agency
          </mj-text>
          <mj-text css-class="script-text" font-size="14px" color="#929292" >
           <span css-class="script-text">Michael Clark</span>
          </mj-text>
        </mj-column>
      </mj-section>

      <mj-section background-color="#F4F4F4">
            <mj-column>
                <mj-text align="center" font-size="25px" font-weight="600" color="#2B2B2B">Our Products</mj-text>
            </mj-column>
      </mj-section> 
      <mj-section background-color="#F4F4F4">
            <mj-column>
                <mj-image src="http://127.0.0.1:5502/assets/watchimage.jpg"/>
            </mj-column>
            <mj-column>
                <mj-text>
                    
                </mj-text>
            </mj-column>

      </mj-section>
      <mj-section background-color="#272727" padding-top="60px" css-class="customer-review">
            <mj-column>
                <mj-text align="center" font-size="35px" font-weight="600" color="#ffffff" padding="0 0 20px">What Our Customers Say</mj-text>
                <mj-button font-size="15px" border-radius="25px">
                    Read the Reviews
                </mj-button>
                <mj-text align="center" font-size="15px"  color="#ffffff" padding="20px 100px 20px 100px" line-height="25px" font-style="italic">
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do
                eiusmod tempor incididunt.consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do
                eiusmod tempor incididunt"
                </mj-text>
                <mj-text align="center" font-size="15px" color="#ffffff" padding="0">
                    - John Doe                
                </mj-text>
                <mj-text align="center" font-size="15px"  color="#ffffff" padding="40px 100px 20px 100px" line-height="25px" font-style="italic">
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do
                eiusmod tempor incididunt.consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do
                eiusmod tempor incididunt"
                </mj-text>
                <mj-text align="center" font-size="15px" color="#ffffff" padding="0 0 10px">
                    - John Doe                
                </mj-text>
            </mj-column>
      </mj-section>
     <mj-section padding="130px 0 30px 0" css-class="mj-section-padding-fix">
        <mj-column>
            <mj-text align="center" font-size="35px" font-weight="600" color="#2B2B2B">Our Latest Blog</mj-text>
            <mj-text align="center" font-size="14px"padding="20px 100px 10px 100px" line-height="25px" color="#929292">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do
                     eiusmod tempor incididunt
            </mj-text>
        </mj-column>
     </mj-section>
     <mj-section padding="0" >
        <mj-group>
            <mj-column>
                <mj-image src="http://127.0.0.1:5502/assets/casualmeet.jpg" />
                <mj-text align="left" font-size="15px" font-weight="600">New Marketing Strategies</mj-text>
                <mj-text line-height="22px">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                </mj-text>
            </mj-column>
            <mj-column>
            <mj-image src="http://127.0.0.1:5502/assets/casualmeet.jpg" />
                <mj-text align="center">fffffff</mj-text>
            </mj-column>
        </mj-group>
     </mj-section>
    </mj-wrapper>
  </mj-body>
</mjml>

I'm not exactly sure whats going on here, as to why my media queries arent applying. Any ideas on how to make responsive css queries with MJML work properly?

I don’t know how, or whether, mjml would deal with a media query, but in general @media is poorly supported on many email clients, see e.g. https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=%40media

Here is the updated code with fix: https://mjml.io/try-it-live/AP4PeW3l1D
I suggest you read the MJML docs. MJML maps your styles to various HTML tags, so always check the generated HTML code to identify where the actual class and styles are applied when applying the Media queries.
